# Add Jars to Grails Project Using Ivy

Tags: grails, groovy, ivy

I'm following the Grails Mail tutorial: http://grails.org/A+simple+EmailerService and it mentions "Then copy two jar files into the application local lib: activations.jar and mail.jar.". Though I can do the manual copy, I was wondering if there's some way I could update my Ivy configuration file to do that pulling automatically instead. I'm not familiar enough with Ivy at this point to know how to look for repositories, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to install the ivy plugin:

```
grails install-plugin ivy
```

Then you can configure your `ivy.xml`:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="apache" module="hello-ivy"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.0"/>
        <dependency org="commons-cli" name="commons-cli" rev="1.0"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Finally, invoke the `grails get-dependencies` command.

The jars will then be downloaded in the project's `lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you get your jars from. For info on Ivy and how it deals with dependencys see this link. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ap05068/index.html