# Reference local Groovy project in Grails app

Tags: grails, groovy

I have created a local Groovy project in Eclipse.

I am now starting to build a Grails project in Eclipse, and I need to reference the Groovy project in some of my controller/service classes.

Normally with Java projects, I would just configure the project build path on the webapp project to reference my local Java project and that would be fine (or if they were both maven projects, update the webapp pom with reference to my local project artefact ID etc).

However, having added the local groovy project to the Grails build path has had no affect and I am unable to access the local Groovy classes - can anyone advise on how I can make the local project available within my Grails project?

Cheers

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336972/add-jars-to-grails-project-using-ivy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export a jar from the groovy project and include that?

Comment: Yep, that worked - seems a shame I cant just link the project source. I built the groovy jar and then included it in the build config as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932516/grails-project-common-java-project-dependency-in-eclipse